# Strange response timing for parallel Ajax calls (PHP/Laravel backend)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a website based on a PHP/Laravel back-end, using MySQL as the database. Recently I have encountered "Too many connections" issues and have been doing some debugging to find out where the bottleneck is.

During my testing, I saw that a certain GET HTTP request was sometimes fired repetitively (dozens of times within a minute), and that this seemed to slow down the global database queries processing, causing connections to remain open for much longer.

I was very surprised, though, to see the timing of responses. Here is my Laravel debugging log output after firing the request 10 times simultaneously from the developer console. The *Starting* marker is right after entering the controller method, the *Returning* marker is right before returning the response.

```
[2019-07-30 09:02:09] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 1
[2019-07-30 09:02:17] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 1 after 7.82s
[2019-07-30 09:02:18] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 2
[2019-07-30 09:02:26] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 2 after 7.82s
[2019-07-30 09:02:26] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 3
[2019-07-30 09:02:29] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 4
[2019-07-30 09:02:29] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 5
[2019-07-30 09:02:29] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 6
[2019-07-30 09:02:30] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 7
[2019-07-30 09:02:31] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 8
[2019-07-30 09:02:45] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 3 after 18.7s
[2019-07-30 09:02:46] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 9
[2019-07-30 09:02:56] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 4 after 26.4s
[2019-07-30 09:02:56] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 5 after 26.5s
[2019-07-30 09:02:56] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 6 after 26.6s
[2019-07-30 09:02:56] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 7 after 26.1s
[2019-07-30 09:02:57] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 8 after 26.2s
[2019-07-30 09:02:57] dev.DEBUG: Starting query 10
[2019-07-30 09:03:02] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 9 after 16.0s
[2019-07-30 09:03:06] dev.DEBUG: Returning from query 10 after 8.7s
```

Is there any reason why, for 10 simultaneous calls, Laravel would fully process the first one, then the second one, then 3-8 in parallel but with 3 finishing before others, then.. etc?

Comment: What happens repeating one more time the 10 requests? Do you get something similar?

Comment: Yes, some requests completing fully, then a few in parallel, then some more..